# How to Get One Entity From Another Entity in a List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to get the username of the user who has the blog Id in their profile.

This code returns all blogs and puts it in a list:

```
        Dim blogs = db.Blogs.Include(Function(b) b.Company)
        Return View(blogs.ToList())
```

I want to include the username to which the blog belongs in the list.  That data is kept in the profile entity (in the field called "BlogId").

This is the profile entity:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class UserProfile

    Public Property UserProfileId() As Integer
    Public Property UserId() As Guid
    Public Property CompanyId() As Integer
    Public Property BlogId() As Integer
    Public Property IsCompanyOwner As Boolean
    Public Property IsBlogOwner As Boolean

End Class

Public Class UserProfileDbContext

    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property UserProfiles As DbSet(Of UserProfile)
End Class
```

How can I get the username into the ToList() to show it in my view?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not see a Username anywhere in the UserProfile object.  Is it in the Company object that your projecting in to the results?

Comment: The UserId is the foreign key to the Users entity.  The blog object has a field called "company" but that's not relevant.

Comment: Could you please post your User object as well in the code.

Comment: It's the standard user object from mvc 3.  I can send if you want, let me know ( i assume you already have it )

Comment: I have no clue what you are referring to.  What standard user object?  Are you using built in FormsAuthentication along with the Membership Provider from ASP.NET?  It's tough to answer a question that doesn't have enough information supplied with it.  If you could provide more information in your question then it will help shed some light on what my recommendation would be.

Comment: "Are you using built in FormsAuthentication along with the Membership Provider from ASP.NET?"  Yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14850/discussion-between-justinmichaels-and-user1477388)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the Membership's user, in that case use your UserId guide to call:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(userId)
```

And then you can reference the name as

```
user.UserName
```

So ideally you'll want to create a new ViewModel class containing only the data you want to send to your view and nothing else. In this case after loading your UserProfile entries, you'll need to enumerate through each one and call the GetUser() and populate each ViewModel entry with that result.

```
Public Class UserProfileViewModel

    Public Property UserProfileId() As Integer
    Public Property UserId() As Guid
    Public Property CompanyId() As Integer
    Public Property BlogId() As Integer
    Public Property IsCompanyOwner As Boolean
    Public Property IsBlogOwner As Boolean
    **Public Property UserName as String**

End Class
```

Comment: So, I can't link together two models, I must create a separate model?

Comment: What I mean is, I can't link together two models in the controller and send them to a view?  I need to, instead, create a separate model that contains all of the info I want in the view?